# What are the recommended security settings for setting up an Amazon RDS database

Tags: amazon-rds

I have a node.js app that's connected to Amazon RDS database, and the app itself is hosted on Elastic Beanstalk.

For it to start work I've allowed "all public connections" in the database and set up so that all inbound traffic can access the database. But if someone get the endpoint link to my database they can access it however they want if I understand things correctly, so I'm now asking you how should I set up the security in the settings for my app?

In the client my app will write the users login data and store some information about them, and they will be able to see their own data and the data from people who are their "friends" in the app.

I've read through some of the documentation but as I'm pretty new to all this I have a hard time understanding what would be the best solution for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a network security perspective you want to make sure that only resources that need to talk to your database are able to do so, i.e. you want a "least-privilege" approach on your network layer.

The way to do that in AWS is through security groups and subnets. Since a database should never be publicly accessible, it should be deployed into a private subnet. That will ensure the database can't be exposed to the internet by accident. While ensuring that resources within your network/VPC are still able to send traffic to the database (in principle).

This is where the next layer of security comes in, we try to restrict access to the database to only the instances that really need it. The way to do that is through security groups. These are essentially instance-level firewalls that control who is allowed to access the instance. Your beanstalk instances will have a security group as well. Security groups can use references to other security groups, so ideally you'd configure the database security group to only allow traffic on the database port (e.g. 3306 for MySQL) from the security group of the Elastic Beanstalk instances.

Afterwards only the beanstalk instances will be able to talk to your database, which is a good first step.

Now that only your application servers can access the database server you should think about how you handle authentication from these servers. You should avoid hard-coding your database credentials on the machines and instead store them in some external service such as the AWS Secrets Manager or the Systems Manager Parameter Store. Afterwards you give the instances permissions to fetch the credentials from there by extending the permissions of the instance role. You should then write code to fetch the credentials + connection string from one of these sources in your application.

For additional security ensure that the connection to the database is encrypted in transit using some form of SSL/TLS, the specific settings depend on your database engine.

I'd also suggest you take a look at the [security section of the RDS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.html) - this has been an overview of the first steps you should consider, but there is always more to do :)

**References**

- [Guide on creating a VPC for your RDS DB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Tutorials.WebServerDB.CreateVPC.html)
- [SSL/TLS configurations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html)
- [Security Groups and RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html)
- [Using the Secrets Manager to rotate DB credentials](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/security/rotate-amazon-rds-database-credentials-automatically-with-aws-secrets-manager/)

Comment: Thanks for writing that out, I will have that as a baseline to start from! I found a tutorial on it here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs_express.html  and here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.db.html if someone is looking at the same kind of issue!

Comment: I highly recommend you provision your db outside of Beanstalk as described in your second link - here is the [documentation on that](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html) - you typically don't want your data to be deleted if you accidentially terminate an environment ;-) Feel free to mark the answer as accepted if it helped you and good luck on your setup!

Comment: Alright, will do! Thanks! Yes it's done!

Comment: I'm planning to go through the material the next days, any chance I could contact you on discord on something if I have any questions after that? Would really be awesome to talk with someone with some experience (i'll wont bother you with useless questions but do my research before)

Comment: @Alexander sorry, I'd prefer you post the well researched questions here - this has the benefit of allowing others to learn from that in the future ;-)

Comment: Ok! I have one question, I try to run my app locally, everything works with the connection to the RDS now (in a secure way) but I can't make it work locally, I get timeout error. Why is that? (I have replaced the secret variables...) "var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME || "ENDPOINT",
    user     : process.env.RDS_USERNAME || "admin",
    password : process.env.RDS_PASSWORD || "PASSWORD",
    port     : process.env.RDS_PORT || "8080"
  });

Comment: Well, if you did what I suggested, the database is only accessible from your applicationservers, which is why you're probably getting a timeout. Can you post that as another question as it's a separate issue?

Comment: I've solved it, I had just put in the wrong port (I reverted some of your suggestions to be able to run it locally)